# Double quotes with List in R

Tags: r, recommenderlab

I am trying to add quotes to a list which is output from predict in 
`recommenderlab` library. which looks something as below. I am facing 
challenge to get this into a concatenated string something like

```
List: 
"Key" 
"value1" "value2" "value3" 
"value4" ..............
```

expected:

```
"value1", "value2", "value3", "value4" ..........
```

tried different ways

used:

```
stri_join_list(v_list, sep = ";", collapse = NULL)
```

### Edited for more information

```
library("recommenderlab")

data("MovieLense")

MovieLense100 <- MovieLense[rowCounts(MovieLense) >100,]

MovieLense100

train <- MovieLense100[1:50]

rec <- Recommender(train, method = "UBCF")

rec

pre <- predict(rec, MovieLense100[101:102], n = 10)

as(pre, "list")
```

when you see the list here it will be in above mentioned format :

```
$`291`
 [1] "Titanic (1997)"                         "Contact (1997)"                         "Alien (1979)"                          
 [4] "Amadeus (1984)"                         "Godfather, The (1972)"                  "Aliens (1986)"                         
 [7] "Sting, The (1973)"                      "American Werewolf in London, An (1981)" "Schindler's List (1993)"               
[10] "Glory (1989)"
```

I want it to be like :

```
"Titanic (1997)", "Contact (1997)", "Alien (1979)"  ....
```

all concatenated as one string, just like above

Thanks but

> paste0(shQuote(list1),collapse=",")

above also not what I am looking as this gives me "\", please let me know what can be done

> cat(paste0(shQuote(v_list[["bi_Marika77"]]),collapse=";"))

-- This worked . Thanks All

**However, I have a small challenge here 
Want to keep the resultant of the above in dataframe where first column will be userid and second column will be concatenated list. please help!**

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please, add some data to use, to copy and paste in R, maybe updating the question with the result of `dput(your_data_here)` if they can be posted. Also, try to share any kind of attempt you've done, to have more chance to have an answer, and not getting downvotes or your question close.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `shQuote()`

```
list1 = as(pre, "list")
paste0(shQuote(list1$`291`),collapse=",")
```

Comment: This gives me something like below:

"\"Titanic (1997)\",\"Contact (1997)\",\"Alien (1979)\",\"Amadeus (1984)\",\"Godfather, The (1972)\",\"Aliens (1986)\",\"Sting, The (1973)\",\"American Werewolf in London, An (1981)\",\"Schindler's List (1993)\",\"Glory (1989)\""  -- I dont want those "\"

Comment: `cat(paste0(shQuote(list1[["291"]]),collapse=","))`

Comment: Awesome!! Thanks a ton.. :)

Comment: Can you please share it as answer? I will mark as accepted or answered...